# Retrieving the distinct count across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, distinct

Say I have the following table in MS SQL Server:

| Make | Model | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Honda | Accord | 1997 |
| Honda | Accord | 1997 |
| Honda | Accord | 1997 |
| Honda | Civic | 2001 |
| Honda | Civic | 2005 |
| Honda | Civic | 2005 |
| Toyota | Corolla | 2010 |
| Nissan | Pathfinder | 1997 |

I want to be able to retrieve the count for the unique combination and get the results like the following:

| Make | Model | Year | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Honda | Accord | 1997 | 3 |
| Honda | Civic | 2001 | 1 |
| Honda | Civic | 2005 | 2 |
| Toyota | Corolla | 2010 | 1 |
| Nissan | Pathfinder | 1997 | 1 |

I thought that I could do use something like `COUNT(DISTINCT())`, but `COUNT(DISTINCT())` across multiple columns isn't valid in MS SQL Server. I feel like I have to use `GROUP BY`, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Isn't this just a `COUNT`..? What `DISTINCT` value, within the group, are you counting here? There's only 3 columns you show us, and they all appear to be in the group. Is there a 4th column you aren't showing us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just group by and count them :

```
select Make ,Model, Year, COUNT(*)
from your table 
group by Make ,Model, Year
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace yourtable with actual table name.

```
Select Make,
       Model,
       Year,
       count(*) Count
From yourtable
Group by Make,
         Model,
         Year
```